# What is the proper way to convert JSON to Yaml in Swager, and invoke it?

Tags: json, yaml, swagger

I need to create new tasks in jira using open AI and REST APIs end points. I need to use yaml files so the AI framework can read it.

I tried to format the json file below to yaml in swagger but it throws an erros. It says the component schema field cannot have additional properties. I don't know how to fix this issue. I tried different variations but nothing worked.
[Screenshot from swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weFDv.png)

`Errors
Hide

Structural error at components.schemas.fields
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: project, issuetype, summary
Jump to line 64`

This is the json file I need to convert:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "project": {
            "id": "10"
        },
        "issuetype": {
            "id": "101"
        },
        "summary": "New task"

    }
  }
```

Please, how can I fix this issue?

I tried different variation but nothing worked.

Comment: FYI - Jira Cloud API has an official OpenAPI definition, you can download it from https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/intro/ (the link is in the top right corner of the page).